# Legal Javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters

I am working on a function for pagination on my site and right now I have it that similar code does it for each page, which is a lot of redundant code, so now i want to combine it so that i just have one function for all the pages. So far I have it pretty much done and it looks great, but my only problem now is that it also puts together part of the page of each item that the page is about. I think I have come up with a backup solution but I want to try something before I use it. I want to know if it is legal in Javascript to do my first idea.

```
<script>
function test(a){
  var b = 5;
  if(b>0){
    a;
  }else{
    //do something else
  }
}
var c = "if(b<3){document.write('true');}else{document.write('false');}";
var d = "document.write(b+5);";
test(c);
</script>
```

This is an oversimplified version of my problem/idea. I want to call test and pass either c or d through but I don't think it is legal. Think of it as the function is on an external page with var c and d as on different pages calling the external function. Var b represents messing with the data before I want to use it.

If there is a way to use this idea but tweaking it a little so it would work, what would it be?

Comment: My backup idea is returning the results from the function and then instead of having c and d as variables, just use them outside of the function.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is something called a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks).

```
function test(callback){
  var b = 5;
  if(b>0){
    callback(b);
  }else{
    //do something else
  }
}
var c = function(myArgument) {
    if (myArgument<3) { 
        console.log('true');
    } else { 
        console.log('false');
    };
};
var d = function(){ console.log(b+5); };
test(c);
```

You have to call the callback function with an argument due to variable scoping.